# XPC and Exception handling

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xpc, nsxpcconnection

I have an *LaunchAgent* using *HockeyApp* for crash reporting. Now I noticed that uncaught exception where not reported by *HockeyApp*, like they would have been in a normal macOS app.

For example:

```
- (void)upperCaseString:(NSString *)aString withReply:(void (^)(NSString *))reply {
    NSArray *array = [NSArray array];
    reply([array objectAtIndex:23]);
}
```

Never reaches `NSUncaughtExceptionHandler`, but the console logs:

```
<NSXPCConnection: 0x7fe97dc0f110> connection from pid 44573: Warning: Exception caught during invocation of received message, dropping incoming message and invalidating the connection.
```

The question is how to get unhandled exception reported with *HockeyApp*.

Answer (score 3):

#### Problem:

XPC seems to have its own *@try @catch block*, which catches unhandled exceptions inside a method, logs the exception and then the calls `-[NSXPCConnection interruptionHandler]`.

This issue is reported to Apple under [rdar://48543049](http://rdar://48543049).

**NOTE:** These are **not** copy & past solutions, carefully evaluate your crash reporting framework. I link to implementation details of *PLCrashReporter*.

#### Solution A:

*@try @catch block*:

```
- (void)upperCaseString:(NSString *)aString withReply:(void (^)(NSString *))reply {
    @try {
        NSArray *array = [NSArray array];
        reply([array objectAtIndex:23]);
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSUncaughtExceptionHandler *handler = NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        if (handler) {
            handler(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

**Discussion**

*HockeyApp* uses *PLCrashReporter* for crash reporting. *PLCrashReporter* registers an `NSUncaughtExceptionHandler` ([code](https://github.com/plausiblelabs/plcrashreporter/blob/05d34741d3a90bbed51214983110943831ae5943/Source/PLCrashReporter.m#L630)). So the above code will forward the exception to the *PLCrashReporter* exception handler and terminates ([code](https://github.com/plausiblelabs/plcrashreporter/blob/05d34741d3a90bbed51214983110943831ae5943/Source/PLCrashReporter.m#L332-L338)) the XPC.

[Mattie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288405/mattie) suggest to *@throw* the exception again, to trigger the internal XPC *@catch* block and possible internal clean-up and logging. **This is something to consider**. Especially if you have a custom `interruptionHandler` on `NSXPCConnection` in the LaunchAgent/Server side of the connection!

For now I side with not throwing it again, because **my** XPC is complete stateless and should be fine just crashing.

The downside to *Solution A* is that **every** method exposed via XPC requires this *@try @catch block*.

#### Solution B:

Use a `NSProxy` that catches all unhandled exceptions as `NSXPCConnection exportObject`:

```
@interface LOUncaughtExceptionHandlerProxy : NSProxy {
    NSObject *_object;
}
@end

@implementation LOUncaughtExceptionHandlerProxy

- (instancetype)initWithObject:(NSObject *)object
{
    NSParameterAssert(object);
    _object = object;
    return self;
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    return [_object methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation
{
    @try {
        [invocation invokeWithTarget:_object];
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSUncaughtExceptionHandler *handler = NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        if (handler) {
            handler(exception);
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Setup within the `NSXPCListener` listener:

```
- (BOOL)listener:(NSXPCListener *)listener shouldAcceptNewConnection:(NSXPCConnection *)newConnection {
    XPC *exportedObject = [XPC new];
    LOUncaughtExceptionHandlerProxy *proxy = [[LOUncaughtExceptionHandlerProxy alloc] initWithObject:exportedObject];
    newConnection.exportedObject = proxy;
    newConnection.exportedInterface = [NSXPCInterface interfaceWithProtocol:@protocol(XPCProtocol)];
    [newConnection resume];
    return YES;
}
```

All details of *Solution A* apply to *Solution B*.

#### Solution Z:

On macOS is possible to use the *ExceptionHandling.framework*, the problems with it are very well outlined in [BITCrashExceptionApplication.h](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Mac/blob/6a6e31c3cafd4991672bcbaf1a48e135a878ae5b/Classes/CrashReporting/BITCrashExceptionApplication.h#L49-L77).

**Discussion**

It is never a good sign when a framework is not ported to iOS. Also note [Matties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288405/mattie) comment:

> I've had interactions with Apple that directly indicate that ExceptionHandling.framework is no longer supported. And, in my experience while working on Crashlytics, it had some fundamental interoperability issues beyond what is indicated in that quoted [header](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Mac/blob/6a6e31c3cafd4991672bcbaf1a48e135a878ae5b/Classes/CrashReporting/BITCrashExceptionApplication.h#L49-L77).

Comment: Solution 1 is great, and 2 is very clever! I would, however, consider adding an `@throw` statement at the end of your `@catch` blocks. Right now, you are changing the runtime behavior - though that could be your intention. Also: I've had interactions with Apple that directly indicate that ExceptionHandling.framework is no longer supported. And, in my experience while working on Crashlytics, it had some fundamental interoperability issues beyond what is indicated in that quoted header. Though, I'm afraid I do not have those details recorded.